# ASP.NET MVC required parameters in controller method

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I was wondering if it's possible to have something like:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public JsonResult AddTextFile(string path)
    {
        if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(path))
        { 
            // return error 
        }
    }
```

But in the case where I might have a lot of parameters in my controller method I don't want to use `string.IsNullOrEmpty()` for each one. I know that I could use view-models with a `[Required]` field indicator and that will allow me to use `ModelState`, but because these are all API endpoints, I'm requiring information through get parameters.

Is there an elegant way of requiring controller method parameters, so that if any of them are not set it would return a generic response message?

Comment: " but because these are all API endpoints, I'm requiring information through get parameters."  You can use models with GET.  Follow a MVC tutorial to find out how.

Comment: @Amy My parameters in the controller method are not necessarily always also existent in my models. For example, there is no such `path` in the `TextFile` model. I'm trying to figure out if in any generic case it is possible to make a controller method require certain parameters so that if they are not present we can simply throw an error as a JSON perhaps instead of even entering the method for any logic.

Comment: I'm not following what the issue is.  This is all perfectly solvable using model validation.

Comment: @Amy Could you possibly provide any links to a tutorial as you mention, that might help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

Use a complex object as the parameter:

```
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult AddTextFile(MyObject obj) {
    if(!ModelState.IsValid) { 
        // return error 
    }
}

public class MyObject {
    [Required]
    public string Path { get; set; }
}
```

The properties of MyObject will be taken from the query parameters, like: /addtextfile?path=blah

And the model validation will apply.